# std::bind() error: cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::io_service::run" is intended

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

While trying to compile this in Visual C++ 2015

```
  auto worker = std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &(this->service));
```

I'm getting errors:

```
error C2783: 'std::_Binder<_Ret,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Ret'
note: see declaration of 'std::bind'

error C2783: 'std::_Binder<_Ret,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Fx'
note: see declaration of 'std::bind'

error C2783: 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Fx'
note: see declaration of 'std::bind'
```

Additionally, IntelliSense complains with:

```
cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::io_service::run" is intended
```

I see that there are 2 overloads of `boost::asio::io_service::run`. But how can I specify which one to use?

With `boost::bind` the code compiles just fine:

```
  auto worker = boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &(this->service));
```

Comment: Just use a lambda... >_>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `boost::asio::io_service::run` has two overloads, you need to specify which to use when using it as a function pointer<sup>(1)</sup>. This needs to be done by casting it to the right function signature:

```
static_cast<std::size_t(boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run)
```

Since this looks horrible, I suggest to use a lambda instead of the bind expression. Inside a lambda, the normal overload resolution takes place, so you don't need to specify the overload explicitly:

```
auto worker = [this]{ return service.run(); };
```

---

<sup>(1) The problem is that `std::bind` takes the function by an unrestricted template argument, so the rules of template type deduction apply instead of overload resolution. C++ can't determine what the type of `_Fx` should be here, since you pass something whose type is not specified. Even if there was a trick such that C++ can try to resolve the overload when using the fact that the bound arguments are going to be passed to the function, note that actually both overloads are possible here: The overload with `boost::system::error_code & ec` would simply be not bound and "curried" instead (specifying the value for that parameter is delayed to the point when `worker` is called).</sup>

Comment: @leemes, Don't you pass a copy of the `this` object?

Comment: I know, but it's not worse than passing a copy of `&(this->service)` via `bind`. I make sure `this` is alive for the whole duration the io_service is running.

Comment: If `this` is not garantueed to survive the lambda, but the service does (it needs to) you can pass a pointer to the service by value. With C++14: `[s = &(this->service)]{ s->run(); }` or with C++11 using a temporary variable before the lambda: `auto s = &(this->service); auto worker = [s]{ s->run(); };`